# string from jquery post returned data

Tags: jquery, post, substring

I have a jquery post like this

```
jQuery.post("script_myrequisition.php", {"user_empno":user_no}, function(data) { 

    jQuery('#type2').html(data);
    var pageHtml =jQuery ( data);


 if(substr(pageHtml,0,2)=='No'){ jQuery('#cancel').hide();}
 else{      jQuery('#cancel').show();}
 });
```

Below in html I have this

```
<input id='cancel' name='cancel' type='Submit' value='Cancel Selected' />
```

Data returned by post method contains either " No records found" or "total No. of records =x followed by records in tabular form".

This is not working. The cancel button is not showing up. please help

Comment: why are you doing `pageHtml =jQuery ( data);`

Comment: try `jQuery.post("script_myrequisition.php", {
    "user_empno": user_no
}, function (data) {
    jQuery('#type2').html(data);
    var pageHtml = jQuery(data);

    if (data.substring(0, 2) == 'No') {
        jQuery('#cancel').hide();
    } else {
        jQuery('#cancel').show();
    }
});`

Comment: I used simply data. It did not work. In both cases, javascript error says object required

Comment: what is the value of `data`

Comment: Add it as your answer so that I can vote

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `data` is a string, so there is no need to create a jQuery wrapper object for it, just use it to get the substring

```
jQuery.post("script_myrequisition.php", {
    "user_empno": user_no
}, function (data) {
    jQuery('#type2').html(data);

    jQuery('#cancel').toggle(data.substring(0, 2) == 'No');
    // you can use toggle
    //if (data.substring(0, 2) == 'No') {
    //    jQuery('#cancel').hide();
    //} else {
    //    jQuery('#cancel').show();
    //}
});
```